Shortcuts appear again in new tab Firefox
For a few days now, every time I open a new Firefox tab, the same shortcuts appear again even though I have removed them several times.
Example:

Open Firefox and show all the shortcuts

Image of initial situation

Remove all the shortcuts (amazon, youtube, etc ...)
Close Firefox
Open Firefox again and the shorcuts have returned

How can I solve that?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


In Settings, you control what appears on a new tab:



In about:config, there are numerous values you'll find by searching on newtab. Here are two to suppress advertising; set them to false:


browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.showSponsored

browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.feeds.topsites
There are many others; feel free to experiment.



Hello yes, I know that but I want is to leave the ones that interest me and remove the ones that don't. I have been using it like this since the option came out and it had always worked, when I deleted one it no longer appeared but for a few days now when I start Firefox it is as if it resets to an exact moment in the past

Yes, see ...showSponsored, in answer. Either all or none, apparently.

No, i have showSponsored to false. What appears to me are visited pages that, even if I remove them, reappear without having visited them.

Try browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.section.highlights.includeVisited .

It didn't work. Besides, what I want is for the ones I delete to disappear, but the ones I don't delete to stay.
